# Marking closed curve using decorations markings without using intersections (TikZ)

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrow-curve

I want to mark my closed curves with `{Latex[length=4mm, cyan]}` like [this](https://ibb.co/0FMS35d). Usually, to mark a curve, I use intersections then mark a new custom mark by `isosceles triangle` and rotate and shift with trial and error. But it's not efficient. I'd like to use something simple like `decorations.marking` or else because I just need to adjust the position of arrow and it's efficient to use. But since my curve is closed, I got a lot of errors when using `decorations.markings`. Is it possible? Please share your knowledge. Thanks in advance.

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, decorations.markings}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture} 
        \begin{scope}[>={Stealth[length=4mm]}]
            \draw[<->, thick] (-4,0)--(4,0) node[below,shift={(-.2,-.2)}]{\Large $x$};
            \draw[<->, thick] (0,-4)--(0,4) node[left, shift={(-.1,-.2)}]{\Large $y$};
        \end{scope}
        \begin{scope}[]
            \draw[line width=1.5pt] (0,0) circle [radius=3cm];
            \draw [red, line width=1.3pt]
            (.1,.4) .. controls (1.2,1.8) and (.4,2.3) .. (-.5,1.9)
            .. controls (-1.2,1.3) and (-1.8,1.5) .. (-2,1.4) 
            to[out=180,in=180] (-2,.2) 
            .. controls (-1.8,.1) and (0,.1) .. (.1,.4) -- cycle;
        \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may simply define a `mark` decoration for each path and set the position of its arrow using the number associated with that decoration once you call it.

```
    \documentclass[border=1mm]{standalone}
    \usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, decorations.markings}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture} 
    \begin{scope}[>={Stealth[length=4mm]}]
    \draw[<->, thick] (-4,0)--(4,0) node[below,shift={(-.2,-.2)}]{\Large $x$};
    \draw[<->, thick] (0,-4)--(0,4) node[left, shift={(-.1,-.2)}]{\Large $y$};
    \end{scope}
    \begin{scope}[thick,decoration={
        markings,
        mark=at position 0.35 with {\arrow[Cyan]{<}}}]
    \draw[line width=1.5pt, postaction={decorate}] (0,0) circle [radius=3cm];
    \end{scope}
    \begin{scope}[thick,decoration={
        markings,
        mark=at position 0.65 with {\arrow[Cyan]{>}}}]
    \draw [red, line width=1.3pt, postaction={decorate}]
    (.1,.4) .. controls (1.2,1.8) and (.4,2.3) .. (-.5,1.9)
    .. controls (-1.2,1.3) and (-1.8,1.5) .. (-2,1.4) 
    to[out=180,in=180] (-2,.2) 
    .. controls (-1.8,.1) and (0,.1) .. (.1,.4) -- cycle;
    \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

[image]