# How to draw an irregular closed shaped in LaTeX

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have the following code in LaTeX that produces a circle in a square with arrow lines, but I want to replace the circle with an irregular shape like the molecule in the image. How can I go about it?

```
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick]
  %x-axes
  \draw [red](4,2) --(7,2);
  %\draw (4,3) --(7,3);
  %\draw (4,4) --(7,4);
  \draw [red,very thick](4,5) --(7,5);
  %y-axes
  \draw [red,very thick](7,2) --(7,5);
  %\draw (6,2) --(6,5);
  %\draw (5,2) --(5,5);
  \draw [red,very thick](4,2) --(4,5);
  %centre
  \fill[blue,very thick] (5.5,3.5) circle(.1);
  %arrows on the right
  \draw [-latex][dashed] (5.5,3.5) --(8,5);
  \draw [-latex][dashed] (5.5,3.5) --(8,4);
  \draw [-latex][dashed] (5.5,3.5) --(8,3);
  \draw [-latex][dashed] (5.5,3.5) --(8,2);
   %arrows on the left
  \draw [-latex][dashed] (5.5,3.5) --(3,2);
  \draw [-latex][dashed] (5.5,3.5) --(3,3);
  \draw [-latex][dashed] (5.5,3.5) --(3,4);
  \draw [-latex][dashed] (5.5,3.5) --(3,5);
  %arrows at the bottom
  \draw [-latex][dashed] (5.5,3.5) --(4,1);
  \draw [-latex][dashed] (5.5,3.5) --(5,1);
  \draw [-latex][dashed] (5.5,3.5) --(6,1);
  \draw [-latex][dashed] (5.5,3.5) --(7,1);
  %arrows at the top
  \draw [-latex][dashed] (5.5,3.5) --(4,6);
  \draw [-latex][dashed] (5.5,3.5) --(5,6);
  \draw [-latex][dashed] (5.5,3.5) --(6,6);
  \draw [-latex][dashed] (5.5,3.5) --(7,6);
  %draw a circle
  \node(circle) [circle, inner sep=0.7cm, draw=red!120] at (5.5,3.5) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
```

[image]

Comment: Look for example [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/563409/marking-closed-curve-using-decorations-markings-without-using-intersections-tik) or [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/471847/drawing-curves-with-latex).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is what you can do with the [hobby](https://ctan.org/pkg/hobby) package:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{hobby}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
  \draw [red,very thick](4,2) --(7,2);
  \draw [red,very thick](4,5) --(7,5);
  \draw [red,very thick](7,2) --(7,5);
  \draw [red,very thick](4,2) --(4,5);

  \fill[blue,very thick] (5.5,3.5) circle(.1);
  %arrows on the right
  \draw [-latex][dashed] (5.5,3.5) --(8,5);
  \draw [-latex][dashed] (5.5,3.5) --(8,4);
  \draw [-latex][dashed] (5.5,3.5) --(8,3);
  \draw [-latex][dashed] (5.5,3.5) --(8,2);
   %arrows on the left
  \draw [-latex][dashed] (5.5,3.5) --(3,2);
  \draw [-latex][dashed] (5.5,3.5) --(3,3);
  \draw [-latex][dashed] (5.5,3.5) --(3,4);
  \draw [-latex][dashed] (5.5,3.5) --(3,5);
  %arrows at the bottom
  \draw [-latex][dashed] (5.5,3.5) --(4,1);
  \draw [-latex][dashed] (5.5,3.5) --(5,1);
  \draw [-latex][dashed] (5.5,3.5) --(6,1);
  \draw [-latex][dashed] (5.5,3.5) --(7,1);
  %arrows at the top
  \draw [-latex][dashed] (5.5,3.5) --(4,6);
  \draw [-latex][dashed] (5.5,3.5) --(5,6);
  \draw [-latex][dashed] (5.5,3.5) --(6,6);
  \draw [-latex][dashed] (5.5,3.5) --(7,6);
  %draw a circle
  \node(circle) [circle, inner sep=0.7cm, draw=red!120] at (5.5,3.5) {};

  \coordinate[label=below left:{$A$}] (A) at (4+0.8,2+0.8);
  \coordinate[label=left:{$B$}]       (B) at (4+0.4,2+1.5);
  \coordinate[label=above:{$C$}]      (C) at (4+0.5,2+2.5);
  \coordinate[label=above:{$D$}]      (D) at (4+1.0,2+2.0);
  \coordinate[label=below:{$E$}]      (E) at (4+1.8,2+2.7);
  \coordinate[label=below left:{$F$}] (F) at (4+2.4,2+2.4);
  \coordinate[label=left:{$G$}]       (G) at (4+2.7,2+1.8);
  \coordinate[label=right:{$H$}]      (H) at (4+2.0,2+1.0);
  \coordinate[label=right:{$I$}]      (I) at (4+2.5,2+0.5);
  \coordinate[label=below left:{$J$}] (J) at (4+1.5,2+0.4);

  \draw[blue,very thick] (A) to [closed, curve through = {(B) (C) (D) (E) (F) (G) (H) (I) (J)}] (A);

  \foreach \j in {A,...,J}{\fill[blue] (\j) circle (0.04);}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot kabenyuk. This is what I needed. Thanks again.

Comment: I am glad to have been of some help!

Answer (score 9):

As your MWE had a strange sketch not so related with the result you wanted, I got a little bit confused, sorry. Anyhow, I will present:

1. A redraw of your original code, as a base of how some commands work.
2. A colorful draw of your desired result.
3. Another method to draw a smooth curve, from which you can choose which one to use.

I let colors in order to make it easier to identify who does what, but not exactly the ones you presented. You may mix and edit code at your will.

#### MWE 01

Please, notice how much simpler are some the code when some commands are used. I invite you check [A very minimal introduction to TikZ](http://cremeronline.com/LaTeX/minimaltikz.pdf).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick]
  \draw [red,very thick] (4,2) rectangle ++(4,4);
  \fill[blue,very thick] (6,4) coordinate (A) circle (0.2); 
  \foreach \t in {0,20, ..., 360}{
    \draw [-latex, dashed]  (A) -- ++(\t:3.5);
  };
  \node(circle) [circle, inner sep=0.7cm, draw=red!120] at (A) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

#### MWE 02

The main MWE. The closed smooth parth is drawn with `... plot[smooth cycle, tension=.7] coordinates {...};`. Notice how `scope` compacts the code to applied `every node`, it makes the code much more clean and clear to read.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick]
  \draw [magenta,very thick] (0,0) node[left]{Solvent} rectangle ++(6.8,5.5);
  
  \draw[green!50!black]  plot[smooth cycle, tension=.7]
  coordinates {(0.8,0.6) (3.3,1.2) (3.3,2.5) (4.4,2.9) (5.5,3.5) (4.8,5.1) (1.3,3.6)};
  
  \node at (7.2,0.1) {$\partial \Omega$};
  \node[green!50!black] at (5.6,5.1) {$\Gamma$};
  \node[green!50!black] at (2.9,5) {$\Omega^{+}$};
  \node[green!50!black] at (2.9,4.1) {$\Omega^{-}$};
  \node[green!50!black] at (2.9,3.1) {Molecule};
  \node[orange] (B) at (5.5,1) {Mobile Ions};
  
  % Base syntax
  % \node[circle, red, inner sep=0.1cm, draw] (circle) at (4.1,-1.3) {$+$};
  % \node[circle, blue, inner sep=0.1cm, draw] (circle) at (2.4,-2.9) {$-$};
  
  \begin{scope}[every node/.style={circle, red, inner sep=0.1cm, draw}]
    \node at (3.7,3.8) {$+$};
    \node at (2,2.2) {$+$};
    \node at (1.7,3.1) {$+$};
  \end{scope}
  
  \begin{scope}[every node/.style={circle, blue, inner sep=0.1cm, draw}]
    \node at (4.6,4.4) {$-$};
    \node at (1.3,1.4) {$-$};
    \node at (1.2,2.3) {$-$};
  \end{scope}
  
  % Base syntax
  % \node[red] (circle) at (6.6,-0.8) {$+$};
  % \node[blue] (circle) at (2,-0.3) {$-$};
  
  \begin{scope}[every node/.style={cyan}]
    \node (P) at (4.7,2.2) {$+$};
    \node at (0.2,1.8) {$+$};
    \node at (0.6,3.8) {$+$};
  \end{scope}
  
  \begin{scope}[every node/.style={teal}]
    \node (N) at (6.1,4.1) {$-$};
    \node at (1.6,4.6) {$-$};
    \node at (0.6,4.6) {$-$};
  \end{scope}
  
  \draw[-latex] (B) -- (N);
  \draw[-latex] (B) -- (P);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

#### MWE 03

The alternative to `plot[smooth]` is using `Bezier curves` with `(A) .. controls (B) and (C) ..`, where `(A)` , `(B)` and `(C)` are given coordinates.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[purple] (9.8,2.5) .. controls (10.8,2) and (12.3,2) .. (11.3,3) .. controls (10.8,3.5) and (12.3,3) ..
  (12.8,4) .. controls (13.3,4.5) and (10,5.4) ..
  (8.8,4.5) .. controls (7.3,3.5) .. cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks FHZ. I  will try inserting this image in my code. Thanks

Comment: @user3307971, glad to help. @kabenyuk answer is also a interesting one using `to [closed, curve through = ...`. Once again, sorry not drawing the exactly path your have shown, but showing techniques to achieve that result.